# IDNA label empty or too long

Tags: python, url, download, python-requests, urllib

I'm trying to run a script of an online course and had to change the source code from python 2 to python 3 syntax. In this script, there is a download of an archive, which I already transformed into:

```
url = "https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~./enron/enron_mail_20150507.tgz"
urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, filename="../enron_mail_20150507.tgz")
```

However, something seems to be wrong with the URL, since it gives me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/xiaolong/development/Python/udacity_intro_to_machine_learning/localpython/lib/python3.5/encodings/idna.py", line 165, in encode
    raise UnicodeError("label empty or too long")
UnicodeError: label empty or too long

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ud120_code_py35fork/tools/startup.py", line 37, in <module>
    data = urllib.request.urlretrieve("http://...")
  File "/home/xiaolong/development/Python/udacity_intro_to_machine_learning/localpython/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 187, in urlretrieve
    with contextlib.closing(urlopen(url, data)) as fp:
  File "/home/xiaolong/development/Python/udacity_intro_to_machine_learning/localpython/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 162, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/home/xiaolong/development/Python/udacity_intro_to_machine_learning/localpython/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 465, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/home/xiaolong/development/Python/udacity_intro_to_machine_learning/localpython/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 483, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/home/xiaolong/development/Python/udacity_intro_to_machine_learning/localpython/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 443, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/home/xiaolong/development/Python/udacity_intro_to_machine_learning/localpython/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 1268, in http_open
    return self.do_open(http.client.HTTPConnection, req)
  File "/home/xiaolong/development/Python/udacity_intro_to_machine_learning/localpython/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 1240, in do_open
    h.request(req.get_method(), req.selector, req.data, headers)
  File "/home/xiaolong/development/Python/udacity_intro_to_machine_learning/localpython/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 1083, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
  File "/home/xiaolong/development/Python/udacity_intro_to_machine_learning/localpython/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 1128, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body)
  File "/home/xiaolong/development/Python/udacity_intro_to_machine_learning/localpython/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 1079, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body)
  File "/home/xiaolong/development/Python/udacity_intro_to_machine_learning/localpython/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 911, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/home/xiaolong/development/Python/udacity_intro_to_machine_learning/localpython/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 854, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/home/xiaolong/development/Python/udacity_intro_to_machine_learning/localpython/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 826, in connect
    (self.host,self.port), self.timeout, self.source_address)
  File "/home/xiaolong/development/Python/udacity_intro_to_machine_learning/localpython/lib/python3.5/socket.py", line 693, in create_connection
    for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
  File "/home/xiaolong/development/Python/udacity_intro_to_machine_learning/localpython/lib/python3.5/socket.py", line 732, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
UnicodeError: encoding with 'idna' codec failed (UnicodeError: label empty or too long)
```

I already tried replacing the `~` and the `.` in the URL with `%7E` and `%2E`, but that didn't help at all.

What's wrong with the URL and how can I fix this?

- exact python version: 3.5.1

Comment: The code works perfectly fine for me using 3.5.0 and 3.4.3, what exact version of python3 are you using?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham 3.5.1, added it to the OP